# html routing helpers are making a call against a storing data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

It doesn't make any sense for me; I thought that constraints will only be hit when the user clicks on the link and not when the link is created. Am I missing something here?

With amount of links on the page, opening a new data context and running a query for each route link is a huge performance drawback. Is there a way to set all Html.RouteLink helpers (and others) to not hit the constraints when creating the link?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do database calls each time you check constraint for routes, at least not without proper caching.

Also it actually makes perfect sense:

```
routes.MapRoute("Test1", "test1/{value}", 
    new { controller = "Home", Action = "Index" },
    new { value = "^[0-9]+$" }
);
routes.MapRoute("Test2", "test2/{value}",
    new { controller = "Home", Action = "Index" }
);
```

Now if you wouldn't check constraints while generating, it would always use route `Test1` for generating urls, but then it would not find any matching route when user clicks it.

Comment: Any idea how would I do database caching in this case? I don't want to open new data context each time the routing is used and the constraints are used. Thanks.